# Compilation error with GCC when brace-init.ing an instance of a vector of move-only type with templated constructor with another one

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, move-semantics, uniform-initialization

A colleague of mine has find a strange compilation error with GCC when one tries to brace initialize a `std::vector<Foo>` with another, if `Foo` is move-only but provides a templated constructor, like in the following example:

```cpp
#include <vector>

struct Foo{
    template <class T> Foo(T) {}
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) = default;
};

int main(){
    std::vector<Foo> v1(std::vector<Foo>{}); // ok
    std::vector<Foo> v2{std::vector<Foo>{}}; // compilation error
}
```

(See code and error on [Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/bMY1Yn8ea).)

Is it a bug? If so, where (within the instantiation process, I guess) is GCC making the mistake? In other words, since the code is ok for all three compilers as soon as one removes the templated construtor, what in the latter trips GCC up?

Comment: "Where" doesn't look like an answerable question . If/when the bug is fixed, we can look at the commit and see.

Comment: That doesn't mean that nobody could answer _"this bug has already been reported here, and GCC is wrong at line x of file y"_ or maybe _"I've looked through the files, and it looks like GCC is wrong at line x of file y"_.

Comment: This problem has nothing to do with C++20, which is obviously a language bug of GCC. [reduced](https://godbolt.org/z/71jjGcbPE).

Comment: [Related](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=83264). This looks like a bug in the standard.

Answer (score 3):

If we stop using vector so we can see what constructors are getting used, then maybe it gets more clear what's going on.

```
template <typename T>
struct V {
    V() { std::cout << "V Default\n"; }
    V(const V&) { std::cout << "V Copy\n"; }
    V(V&&) { std::cout << "V Move\n"; }
    V(std::initializer_list<T>) { std::cout << "V list<" << typeid(T).name() << ">\n"; }
};

struct Foo {
    template <class T>
    Foo(T) {  std::cout << "Foo <" << typeid(T).name() << ">\n"; }
    Foo(const Foo&) = delete;
    Foo(Foo&&) { std::cout << "Foo Move\n"; }
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/9qs9bvjjz

Now let's try to copy construct a `V<Foo>` from a `V<Foo>`, using both `()` and `{}`.

```
V<Foo> v0{};
V<Foo> v1(v0);
V<Foo> v2{v1};
```

To create `v1` with both gcc and clang, we get "V Copy", copy ctor of V chosen as best.  For `v2` on clang we get "V Copy" as well, but for gcc, we get "V list<Foo>".  It's using the initializer list constructor of V instead of the copy constructor.

Now, one should wonder, how did we get a `std::initializer_list<Foo>` from a list of one element of `V<Foo>`?  That's because of the template constructor of `Foo`, which provides a conversion constructor to allow creating a `Foo` from a `V<Foo>`.

gcc acts the same as if we had written:

```
V<Foo> v2( { Foo(v1) } );
```

I think gcc is correct here.

`V<Foo> v2{v1}` is direct-list-initialization and the resolution is done in two phases.  The first is to consider only `std::initializer_list` constructors, then the second is to consider all constructors with the list as the arguments.  The first phase should produce a match, by converting `v1` into a `Foo`, and that's what gcc picks.

In case it's not clear, once the initializer_list constructor is chosen, you get an error with vector because it's not possible to use that constructor with a list of non-copyable objects.  The initializer_list's elements are const and the vector is copy-initialized from it.

Comment: So, a viable solution would be to constrain that constructor (e.g. https://godbolt.org/z/zxG8f7enG), am I right?

Comment: @Bob__, certainly having a class with a non-explicit constructor from anything is a sure to cause problems.   That will fix it, as there is no longer a way to create an initializer_list of Foo.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it a bug?

I think that **GCC is correct in rejecting the program** for the reasons described below:

`std::vector` has a [constructor](https://cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/vector/) that takes an `std::initializer_list`:

```
vector (initializer_list<value_type> il, const allocator_type& alloc = allocator_type());
```

Thus when you wrote:

```
std::vector<Foo> v2{std::vector<Foo>{}};
```

In the above statement, the quoted initializer list ctor of `vector` can be used/utilised.

Moreover, the **copy constructor `Foo::Foo(const Foo&)` will be used** here since from [dcl.init.lst](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4140/dcl.init.list):

> An object of type `std::initializer_list<E>` is constructed from an initializer list as if the implementation allocated a temporary array of `N` elements of type `const E`, where `N` is the number of elements in the initializer list. **Each element of that array is copy-initialized with the corresponding element of the initializer list**, and the std::initializer_list object is constructed to refer to that array.

(emphasis mine)

But since the copy constructor is `deleted` we get the mentioned error. You can confirm that this is indeed the case by `defaulting` the copy ctor instead of deleting it as done in [this](https://godbolt.org/z/rvvKdK9xE) demo and as we can notice [there](https://godbolt.org/z/rvvKdK9xE) the program works(compiles) without any issues.

Comment: How should a vector initialize itself from an initialized list of vectors of the same type as itself?

Comment: Shouldn't the initializer list constructor only match a list of `Foo`?  That is a list of `std::vector<Foo>`, i.e. what constructor does `std::initializer_list<std::vector<Foo>>` match?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Just like when it does when we remove the templated ctor. [Demo1](https://godbolt.org/z/dYb7YK6hh) or modified [Demo2](https://godbolt.org/z/jqjM1jxjc) . Or are you implying something about infinite recursion or something else. I don't see any problem when the vector to be initialized is of the same type as the initializer vector. Or i missed something obvious?

Comment: If we remove the constructor, it is not chosen (obviously). If we modify the constructor, it is also not chosen (it is not viable). These cases are not interesting. But if we leave the constructor as is, it is chosen by gcc and not chosen by other compilers. Now are you saying that (1) it should be chosen and pass (no compiler does this); (2) it should be chosen and fail (only gcc does this); or (3) it should not be chosen at all (the other compilers do this)?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. To my current understanding I think that it(the templated version) should *not be* chosen.

Comment: Ok why? What should prevent it from being chosen?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Because we're passing a vector of the same type and so the templated version will never be preferred over the other two ctors.

Comment: An std::initializer_list ctor is always preferred over other ctors, even if it is templated and the others are not.

Comment: ... [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/d84s9fGT6) and [source](https://eel.is/c++draft/over.match.list).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I was not talking about the initializer list ctor when i said: *"so the templated version will never be preferred over the other two ctors"*. In particular, i was talking about the templated ctor provided in OP's example which does not take an initializer list. I think you misread/misinterpreted my last comment. Moreover, note that(as you also mentioned) i already know that the initializer list ctor will be preferred over others. But i was not talking about the initializer list ctor to begin  with.

Comment: Another example of how the chosen implementation of braced initialization has complicated things.

Comment: @JHBonarius Yes, agreed.

Comment: The problem is not with the OP's class. The problem is with `vector`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Upon looking further into the standard, i realize that GCC is correct in rejecting the program. I have quoted the source for my claim in my answer. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: The problem here is that the standard mandates to look at the initializer list constructor at all, according to https://cplusplus.github.io/CWG/issues/2137.html. Which gcc implements and the other compilers seemingly don't.

Comment: @TrentP It matches the constructor that accepts `std::initializer_list<Foo>`, because `Foo` is constructible from everything, including `std::vector<Foo>`.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.  Yes, that is as I've explained in my answer.  I see after I made my answer, Anoop reversed his to match mine.

Comment: @TrentP My answer already said that the initializer list ctor will be used. I did not reversed it to match yours. Instead after reading more from the standard and playing with different examples i corrected my analysis.

Comment: Ok, sure, three hours after I made my answer your completely reversed yours to match mine, but my answer being there had nothing to do with it and you did it completely on your own.

Comment: @TrentP Believe what you want/like.